# RabbitMQ PHP AMQP Library - Get message headers

Tags: php, header, amqp, php-amqplib

I have got a simple queueing system which, obviously, takes messages and publishes them.

However, due to a new development in the system, we now need to check for the `x-death` headers from the exchange, however, I can't seem any documentation on how to retrieve that through the PHP AMQP Library.

Anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check for it in `application_headers` property.

Here is a brief modified code from example:

```
/**
 * @param \PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage $msg
 */
function process_message($msg)
{
    $headers = $msg->get('application_headers');
    $props = ['x-death'];

    // OR

    $props = $msg->get_properties();
    $props['application_headers']['x-death'];

    $msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_ack($msg->delivery_info['delivery_tag']);
}


$ch->basic_consume($queue, $consumer_tag, false, false, false, false, 'process_message');
```

Comment: I did try that, but the `application_headers` is empty :/ Do you know of any reason why that would be? Am I not doing something which populates the `application_headers`?

Comment: `application_headers` are populated by the library internals. If it empty (empty array) it's ok and mean that no headers are set for the message.

Comment: Right, in which case it seems that I need to make some changes to my queues & exchanges. Thanks a lot @zaq178miami !

Answer (score 9):

Just to add some more to @pinepain's answer. You can do the following too:

```
/** @var AMQPMessage $message */
$props = $message->get_properties();
/** @var AMQPTable $applicationHeaders */
$applicationHeaders = $props['application_headers'];
$xdeath = $applicationHeaders->getNativeData()['x-death'];
```